# How to prove yourself not raping your short term girlfriend?

Tags: sexual-assault

How to legally prove yourself not raping your short term girlfriend if you are actually just had sex with her that both agreed?

Conditions: Your short term girlfriend lived with you for a few days. She always show her nude body in front of you and called the police to cry and scream all the time that you rape her. She is also a foreigner that holds the visa passport.

Comment: In most jurisdictions the burden of proof is on the prosecution.  They wouldhave to prove that she did not consent, you only have to sshow that it is reasonably possible to doubt her argument.

Comment: What is some example that would make it doubtful in other cases?

Comment: I am not familiar with any jurisdiction that *doesn't* put the burden of proof on the prosecution, so I can't comment on "other cases."